# iOS XCode launch screen storyboard does not display image from asset catalog when running on device

Tags: uiimageview, ios11, xcode9, launch-screen, asset-catalog

I'm running into an issue where an iOS app project using Launch Storyboard does not display some images from the asset catalog. But it can display another image in the same image view. This tells me that the image view is set up correctly, and something is wrong with the image itself

**How can I understand why my image is not displayed on launch screen when starting app?**

I checked the asset catalog membership, and the images are members of the correct target. The image displays in the interface builder preview.

I checked and images are not displayed when saved in either JPG or PNG format.

The image previews fine on Storyboard preview.

I tried using smaller image, so it doesn't seem to be a file size issue.

Does not work on either device or simulator.

This image displays:
[image]

This image does not display:
[image]

Comment: try adding all sizes for the image (@2x, @3x)

Comment: It's because this is your app's icon. At build time, it is removed from the asset catalog and placed into the app bundle.